# Convex hulls intesection

Tags: geometry

There are 2 datasets:

${(0, 0),(−0.1, 0.1), (−0.3, −0.2), (0.2, 0.1)}$ and ${(0.2, −0.1),(−1.1, −1.0),(−1.3, −1.2),(−1, −1), (1, 1),(0.9, 1.2),(1.1, 1.0)}$

I want to show that this data isn't linearly separable. One way is to deal with convex hulls. How to show that convex hulls of these sets intersect?

I've tried to do it graphically with python, but that was completely unsuccessful

Or maybe there is an analytical way to prove that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that $(0,0)$ belongs to the line segment connecting $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$.